# can we have "or" in get url method? js

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, character

the situation is,
the backend already have things done such that I can search for items by first / last name but not combined.

so in url something like this would `http://127.0.0.1:8000/name/list/?first=abc`

this would return correctly with someone's first name that is abc.
The thing is, I would have no idea if the user is entering to search for first / last

Is there a way to write it so it's searching with something like first or last?

I know that there is `&` which is used as `and` but I have no idea if there's a way to search for or....

So both first and last name would be searching for matching letters such as `'abc'`

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: If the backend doesn't support it, then changing the URL format will not do anything except give you errors.

Comment: If it is first search first if it is last search last?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thx thx, I thought there might be something can be done in frontend too.